# Controlar el Ingreso del Punto (.) como Valor Inicial en un EdiText

Tags: android

Tengo EdiText numérico, requiero que el primer valor ingresado sea un número 0-9 y no un punto (.) como valor Inicial, primero valido que el editext no este vacío. pero también requiero que el usuario coloque un número y después  si se requiere el punto (.)

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String n = entrada.getText().toString().trim();
            if(entrada.getText().toString().equals(""))  {
                resultado.setText("");
                entrada2.setText("");
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingrese un Valor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg.show();
            } else {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void afterTextChanged() {
    String n = entrada.getText().toString().trim();
    if(n.isEmpty())  {
        resultado.setText("");
        entrada2.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ingrese un Valor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (n.startsWith(".")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No puede empezar por punto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Genial, el texto no está vacío ni empieza por punto!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude.

Un saludo

Lección del mes: [¿Qué son y para qué sirven los DP en Android?](https://tyris-software.com/que-son-y-para-que-sirven-los-dp-en-android/)